# Apache POI Performance

Tags: java, performance, apache-poi

I'm having performance problems with Apache POI. I've read the FAQ where it refers to a performance test. I've run this test with logging off and 4gb of heap and I can't get the tests to run faster than 22 seconds.

This is the test I'm running:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/SSPerformanceTest.java

The [FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109) says that if I can't get this test to run in under 3 seconds with 50,000 rows and 50 columns that "the problem is with your environment". I've read other comments around the web referring to disabling poi logging and increasing the heap size, but nothing seems to help.

What else can I check to fix my environment?

Machine Specs (Personal desktop machine):

```
CPU: Intel i7 8-cores
RAM: 16GB
OS: Windows 7 64bit
JDK: 1.8.0_66
POI: 3.13
JVM Params: -Xmx4g -Xms4g -Dorg.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.poi.util.NullLogger
Command Arguments: XSSF 50000 50 0
```

I should also mention that the Apache POI jars I'm using came from [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cpoi%7C3.13%7Cjar)

I've created a test project on github where you can simply clone the project and run:

```
mvn exec:java
```

I hard coded the parameters I'm using so you do not have to enter anything special on the command line. The documentation says this should run in under 3 seconds.

The test project is located here:
https://github.com/mikedehaan/poi-test

Comment: A mention of your hardware specs might help and the info how exactly you run this.

Comment: Good point...Updating now.

Comment: Also, can you write what OS are used in this test? Windows, Linux? What version? For perfomance issue, sometimes it's more important then jdk version.

Comment: Are you using `-Xms` or `-Xmx` to set the heap size? Also, have you tried running the test with the fourth Program argument as `0` (e.g., `HSSF 50000 50 0`)?

Comment: yes, I'm using -Xmx4g -Xms4g with XSSF 50000 50 0

Comment: Edited to include requested information so far.

Comment: Java 8 Update 25 is a bit outdated. Perhaps try upgrading to Update 66 to see if they threw a tweak in there that might help you out?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.8.0_66 with similar results.

Comment: I saw that 2G seems to still be too low, with 4G memory it runs a lot faster, albeit still not "in a few seconds"...

Comment: Just posted a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995058/apache-poi-much-quicker-using-xssf-than-hssf-what-next) I see the same results on my own machine with similar specs, although running Windows 10. It's really quite frustrating. I found your post on the mailing list. It's a shame nobody has replied yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test results on my machine:

- HSSF: 2 sec
- SXSSF: 5 sec
- XSSF: 27 sec

Machine specs:

```
CPU: Intel i3-2100, 3.10 GHz, 4-cores
RAM: 16GB
OS:  Windows 7 64bit
JDK: 1.7.0_76
```

I made profiling and found out that `XSSF` is slow due to the synchronized methods in `xmlbeans` and `poi-ooxml-schemas` libraries. You can notify poi developers and ask to check this case.

Comment: I see similar results in my environments. I believe you've found the answer. I've shared this information on the apache poi user list. Hopefully they respond.  Thank you!